# Enumerate with lowercase letters not starting at "a. "

Tags: lists, enumerate

I need an enumerate list that starts at `c.` instead of `a.`. Is this even possible? If so how do I do it?

I tried `\begin{enumerate}[c. ]` but that didn't work. I just got `c.` before each item.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `start=3`  with `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.,start=3]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `\addtocounter{enumi}{2}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*. ]
    \addtocounter{enumi}{2}
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]